# Jquery and IE 7 - selected property not working for multiple select boxes, even when options are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a dropdown (multiple select).  I choose a few values, they are highlighted correctly, but jQuery doesn't recognize them as selected.  this works in firefox and chrome, doesn't work in IE.  this is the code

```
$("#myBox" +" option").each(function() 
{
  if ($(this).attr("selected") == true) 
  {
     // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: What about just `if (this.selected) { /* something */ }` ?

Comment: However what you have there should in fact work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried

```
$("#myBox option:selected").each(function(){
   //do something
});
```

This is I usually handle select boxes and this seems to work well for me.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$("select").each(function(){

    $(this).children("option:selected").each(function(){

       //handle this $(this).val()

    });                 
});
```

works fine for me =]